# No access to vector in vector class

Tags: c++, vector

I'm making a simple vector class and I'm having problems initialising my object. This is the basis of my program/problem:

```
int main() {
bla v1(100);

int i=0;  
while (i < 101) {
    v1.initialise(2.0, i);
    i++;
};
return 0;
}
```

the header file:

```
class bla {
private:
  int m_size;
  std::vector<double> v;
public:
  bla (int i) {
     m_size = i;
     std::vector<double> v(m_size);
  }
  void initialise(double gg, int i) {
     v[i] = gg;
  };  
}
```

It seems that the constructor works fine, but when I try and initialise all elements of v1 to 2.0, there is a segmentation fault, like v[i] cannot be reached inside initialise().

Any help welcome,

Ryan

Comment: Reimplementing `std::vector` by writing class using... `std::vector` is so pointless - I'd recommend you to [read what `std::vector` can give you](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast reply! I think I might have made a typo there but unfortunately I get segmentation fault for the first element of the vector.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus - it is, I agree, but I'll ask you to just play along here.

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
bla (int i) {
   m_size = i;
   std::vector<double> v(m_size);
}
```

into:

```
bla (int i) : m_size(i), v(m_size) {
}
```

and only then

```
while (i < 101) {
```

into:

```
while (i < 100) {
//         ^^^
```

Comment: Beat me to it, have a +1. But you could add some explanation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but even v1.initialise(2.0, 1) gives me a segmentation fault

Comment: @ryan: mind to share the **entire** code that "gives you segmentation fault" ??

Comment: Wait, no it works now! the edit you made was the difference. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In

```
bla (int i) {
   m_size = i;
   std::vector<double> v(m_size);
}
```

you have a local variable `v`, which hides the member variable.
You're initialising the local vector to have `m_size` elements, and it's thrown away when the constructor finishes, leaving the member vector untouched and empty.
Since the member vector is empty, `v[i] = gg;` is invalid for all `i`.

You should use an initialiser list:

```
  bla (int i): m_size(i), v(i) {}
```

Also,

```
while (i < 101)
```

would iterate over the range `[0, 100]`, which has *101* elements, but your vector only has 100.
This will lead to more problems, most likely another crash.